# Stuck on creating a object via for loop

Tags: java, arrays, loops, object, banking

I am stuck in creating in an object for an account, and I don't know where the problem is. My output shows only the recent inputted value. I would like to see the printed details (especially different id's) that I've created, and I don't know how to do that.

Please check my code because I think my loop has a bug in it, somewhat shows display messages that doesn't need to display.

**BankSystem.java:**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BankSystem {

    public static void main(String[] args)  throws IOException {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        BankAccount account[] = new BankAccount[5];
        BankClient client[] = new BankClient[5];
        BankSystem myBankSystem = new BankSystem();
        String MainMenu;

        do {
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("------PLP BANK SYSTEM------");
            System.out.println("Main Menu: ");
            System.out.println("[A]ccount Management" );
            System.out.println("[C]lient Management" );
            System.out.println("[Q]uit" );
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.print("Please select letter: ");
            MainMenu = in.nextLine();

            switch (MainMenu.toLowerCase()) {
                case "a": 
                    System.out.println("");
                    System.out.println("------PLP BANK SYSTEM------");
                    System.out.println("Account Management:" );
                    System.out.println("[N]ew Account" );
                    System.out.println("[A]Apply Interest to All Accounts" );
                    System.out.println("[L]ist All Accounts" );
                    System.out.println("[F]ind an Account" );
                    System.out.println("[D]eposit to an Account" );
                    System.out.println("[W]ithdraw from an Account" );
                    System.out.println("[R]eturn to Main Menu" );
                    System.out.println("");
                    System.out.print("Please select letter: " );
                    String AccountManagement = in.nextLine(); 

                    switch (AccountManagement.toLowerCase()) {
                        case "n": //NEW ACCOUNT    
                            System.out.print("Please input your desired ID number: " );
                            int id = in.nextInt();
                            System.out.print("Please input your desired Balance: " );
                            double balance = in.nextDouble();
                            System.out.print("Please input your desired Interest Rate: " );
                            double interestRate = in.nextDouble();

                            // IS THE PROBLEM IS HERE ON MY LOOP?                                 
                            for (int i=0; i<account.length; i++) {
                                account[i] = new BankAccount(id, balance, interestRate);
                            }        

                            break;                                               
                        case "a": //APPLY INTEREST TO ALL ACCOUNTS
                            System.out.println("For all accounts, compute and compound:" );
                            System.out.println("[M]onthly" );
                            System.out.println("[Q]uarterly" );
                            System.out.println("[A]nnually");
                            System.out.println("[C]ancel");

                            break;                        
                        case "l": //LIST ID NUMBERS OF ALL ACCOUNTS
                            System.out.println("List of all Accounts: ");
                            account[1].printDetails(); // OR THE PROBLEM IS HERE?
                            account[2].printDetails();

                            break;                            
                        case "f": //FIND ACCOUNT
                            System.out.println("Enter ID number: " );

                            break;                            
                        case "d": //DEPOSIT
                            System.out.println("Enter ID number: " );
                            System.out.println("Enter Deposit amount: " );

                            break;                            
                        case "w": //WITHDRAW
                            System.out.println("Enter ID number: " );                              
                            System.out.println("Enter Withdraw amount: " );

                            break;                        
                        case "r": // RETURN
                            break;                      
                    }                                                                 
                case "c":
                    System.out.println("");
                    System.out.println("------PLP BANK SYSTEM------");
                    System.out.println("Client Management:");
                    System.out.println("[N]ew Client" );
                    System.out.println("[L]List All Clients" );
                    System.out.println("[F]ind a Client" );
                    System.out.println("[R]eturn to Main Menu" );
                    System.out.println("");
                    System.out.print("Please select letter: " );
                    String ClientManagement = in.nextLine();

                    switch (ClientManagement.toLowerCase()) {                            
                        case "n": //NEW CLIENT                                
                            System.out.println("Enter ID number: " );
                            System.out.println("Please input your Name: " );
                            System.out.println("Please input your account ID number: " );

                            break;                                
                        case "l": //LIST ALL CLIENT
                            break;                                   
                        case "f": //FIND A CLIENT
                            System.out.println("Enter ID number: " );

                            break;                           
                        case "r":
                            break;                                
                        default: 
                            System.out.println("Invalid entry, Please try again!"); 
                            break;                             
                    }                                                                               
                default: 
                    System.out.println("Invalid entry, Please try again!");  
            }
        } while (!MainMenu.equals("q"));

        System.out.println("Thank you for using my program!"); 
    }
}
```

**BankAccount.java:**

```
public class BankAccount {
    private double balance;
    private double interestRate;
    private int id;

    public BankAccount (int id, double initialDeposit, double initialIntRate){
        //Constructor

        this.id=id;
        this.balance=initialDeposit;
        this.interestRate=initialIntRate;      
    }

    public double getBalance(){
        return balance;
    }

    public double getInterestRate(){
        return interestRate;
    }

    public int getIDNumber(){
        return id;
    }

    public void printDetails() {
        System.out.println("ID Number is: " +id );
        System.out.println("Current balance is: "+balance );
        System.out.println("Interest rate is: "+interestRate+"%");
    }

    public double computeMonthlyInterest(){        
        interestRate=balance*interestRate;            
        return interestRate;
    }  

    public void applyMonthlyInterest(){
        this.balance=balance+interestRate;        
    }  

    public void applyQuarterlyInterest(){
        this.balance=balance+(interestRate*3);
    }  

    public void applyAnnualInterest(){
        this.balance=balance+(interestRate*12);        
    }  

    public void deposit(double amount){
        this.balance += amount;
    }

    public boolean withdraw (double amount) {
        if (amount>balance) {
            System.out.println("Withdraw amount is more than balance, Please try again.");
            return false;
        }
        else 
        {
            this.balance -= amount;
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please indent your code. At the moment it's nearly impossible to read. And please describe your problem more preciously (what's the desired behaviour, etc.)

Comment: You one `switch` structur has no `break;` between the `case` statements and there is one `while` missing a body (in the first code snippet)

Comment: Narrow down the problem. Surely most of that code is not relevant to the issue. As others have said, please also take the time to format and indent your code.

Comment: my bad, sorry guys done editing thanks. my problem is when i'am creating a new account. i am just replacing it.

Comment: @RaycharlesDelaCruz Instead of just posting a comment telling us that the solution from [Jamie](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26166190/3755692) helped you, accept his answer

Comment: juru, did the work for me. thanks guys for commenting. i am just new here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you fill the entire array of bank accounts with the latest entered bank account.

```
for (int i=0; i<account.length; i++) {
account[i] = new BankAccount(id, balance, interestRate);

}
```

Instead after receiving the information of a bank account you should just create one new BankAccount and the index of the array should be the current amount of bank accounts +1.

So make a variable to store the current amount of bank accounts, before the do statement.

```
int amountOfBankAccounts = 0;
```

And use it at the location of the for and remove the for

```
if(amountOfBankAccounts < 5) {
  account[amountOfBankAccounts++] = new BankAccount(id, balance, interestRate);
} else {
  System.out.println("Can not create a new account anymore, array is full!");
}
```

That should fix it. Once that works I suggest you take some time to create functions to make your code more readable and reusable.

Comment: how to flag sir juru. sorry i am just new here.
and can i ask for 1 last thing. how about a if statement for FINDING a account id number.

Comment: Just press the V shaped sign on the top left of an answer. I don't really know what you want to find. But if you want to find a BankAccount with a certain id that you provided you can use a loop to go through all bank accounts and use this if statement if(givenId == bankAccounts[i].getIDNumber())

Answer (score 2):

You should really consider breaking your code apart into subroutines; breaking it up will help compartmentalize the different functions.

As to your bug; I think you are saying that all accounts have the same value, and that you are not expecting that.

Your code is as follows, when creating a new account:

```
for (int i=0; i<account.length; i++) {
    account[i] = new BankAccount(id, balance, interestRate);
}
```

Every time you run that line, you are replacing every element in your array with a new BankAccount object.

Comment: what code should i replace instead? i want to make different accounts, not replacing almost spended 3 hours searching for this

Comment: thanks for enlightenment jamie. i know now what to do

Comment: You should also consider putting your bank account objects into a list, rather than an array of fixed size.  Check out the javadoc for collections such as ArrayList or HashMap.